# Create a splashscreen in next/capacitor app?

Tags: next.js, splash-screen, capacitor

I am a beginner in react and capacitor. I have to implement a splashscreen on a next/capacitor app. I have installed @Capacitor/core. This is the relevant code in my capacitor.config.json file:

```
"plugins": {
"SplashScreen": {
  "launchShowDuration": 3000,
  "launchAutoHide": true,
  "androidSplashResourceName": "splash",
  "androidScaleType": "CENTER_CROP"
}
```

However, when I run this app on an android studio emulator the splashscreen does not show at all. Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

you also have to install `@capacitor/splash-screen`

Do

```
npm i @capacitor/splash-screen
```

and it will solve your issue